# what is the easiest way for opcode caching with PHP/Apache?

Tags: php, performance, apache, caching, opcode

I was thinking to use opcode caching for performance profit

what is the easiest way for opcode caching with PHP/Apache ?
and what are the performance improvements ?

I have read about xDebug but I was wondering if there are more options ?

Comment: xDebug is not an opcode cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [APC extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc) as an opcode cache on both my personnal server, and on the servers we are using at work -- and I've almost never run into any kind of trouble with it.

Installation is pretty easy : depending on your Linux distribution, you might want to use something like :

```
sudo aptitude install php5-apc
```

But you'd not necessarily have the last stable version... And I generally prefer using :

```
sudo pecl install apc
```

Which will fetch the last version from PECL and compile it *(Note : you'll probably need to installed a package called `php5-dev`)*.

You'll then have to configure it ; see [Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php) for the directives you can configure.

The performance improvements can vary depending on your server/application, but, on a server that only serves PHP pages *(i.e. if your DB is on another machine)* you might see a drop in CPU load that's quite important *(I've seen CPU load go from 80% to 40-50% on a server, once)*

Xdebug is not related to opcode caching nor performance : as its name indicates, it's useful for debugging.

And Xdebug should not be installed on a production server : it can be a pain, when it comes to performances -- I suppose it's because it "hooks" into PHP and add lots of stuff, like logging many informations useful for debugging ; which means more calculations to do -- which takes time and CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)** : been using it with Mediawiki and the results are significant.

Answer (score 1):

Other popular options are eAccelerator and APC.

Performance improvements will depend on the web app you're caching. [Here are some benchmarks for the Drupal CMS using APC and eAccelerator](http://2bits.com/articles/benchmarking-apc-vs-eaccelerator-using-drupal.html), and [here's the same site's tutorial on installing APC](http://2bits.com/articles/installing-php-apc-gnulinux-centos-5.html) (nice and easy).

Answer (score 0):

On Debian/Ubuntu, try:

```
sudo aptitude install php5-xcache
```

A commercial solution is from Zend, http://www.zend.com